# How to char[] to Hex? C

Tags: c, string, char, hex

So I have kind of hit a road block in my project.
What I am trying to do is figure out a way to take four individual binary characters which are representing flags. Now my last task was to take these four flags and put them in a char[] which wasn't difficult at all. But now, I want to take the four and convert it to a hex.

So for example:

```
O = 1;
C = 1;
Z = 0;
N = 0;

char flags[5];
flags[0] = O;
flags[1] = C;
flags[2] = Z;
flags[3] = N;
```

Now I wanted to make a string or something i can convert the above to a Hex. So for example I want to have 1100 converted to a hex which is 0xC

Now I have tried to make it in to a string first then parse it but I'm confused and lost now. I just can't see to get the right output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int flags;
flags = (O << 3) | (C << 2) | (Z << 1) | N;
sprintf(buffer, "0x%02X", 0xff & flags);
```

`flags` is defined a single `int`-variable containing all your flags.

`buffer` is a char array of sufficient size.

The `0xff & ..` is not needed in this case, but might be some day if your flags variable can get negative and you still only want to have a one byte output (2 hex digits).

Comment: what if i wanted to have the hex be 4 characters long??

Comment: @Prince Kishore: `sprintf(buffer, "%04X", 0xffff & flags);` // assuming that you don't want the 0x-prefix. After 4 hex digits there will be still a 5th character =0 terminating the string.

Answer (score 0):

unsigned char flags = 0;
flags = ((O << 3) | (C << 2) | (Z << 1) | N);

now flag contains the Hex value you need.

Comment: "...the value you need and which you can display as a hex value." Hex is only a representation.

Answer (score 0):

put flags[4]="\0"

we can have a new variable-char pointer pointing to this array of characters.

then you can use `sprintf(newArray[i], "%x", flags[i]);`

this will generate each character into HEX in newArray string, we can get the output by printing the string. `printf("%s\n",newArray);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for convert a byte[] to hex string

Cast your char[] into byte[] or modify the code as you need :)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a byte array to a hex string. For example: {10,11} = "0A 0B"
    /// </summary>
    public static string ByteToHex(byte[] data)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (byte b in data)
        {
            string hex = ByteToHex(b);
            sb.Append(hex);
            sb.Append(" ");
        }

        if (sb.Length > 0)
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the byte to a hex string. For example: "10" = "0A";
    /// </summary>
    public static string ByteToHex(byte b)
    {
        string sB = b.ToString(ConstantReadOnly.HexStringFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        if (sB.Length == 1)
            sB = "0" + sB;

        return sB;
    }
```